# How does EnableColumnVirtualization in a DataGrid work?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

Given the following `Datagrid`:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" HeadersVisibility="Column" 
        IsReadOnly="True"
        VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="true" VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"
        EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Data, IsAsync=True}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Header1" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Property1}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Header2" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Property2, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Why does it not show any rows? When I remove `EnableColumnVirtualization` or set it to `false` everything is normal. `EnableRowVirtualization` may be added or removed without showing any issues.

Is there an explanation for this behavior?

Comment: Just tried to reproduce the problem, but couldn't. Columns and rows appear normally, with or without `EnableColumnVirtualization`. Anyway, have you tried removing the `VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing` and `VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode` declarations? If you just want to enable virtualization for the columns, those are redundant, and may be the cause of your troubles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DataGrid.EnableColumnVirtualization` only creates columns when there is data to display in those columns and it's visibility is set to visible.  This kind of ruins the whole `Visibility=Visibility.Visible` expectation.

If you require there to be column headings even when there is no data, then don't enable column virtualization, but keep row virtualization.

`DataGrid.EnableRowVirtualization` only creates the rows that will be visible on screen.  When coupled with `VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode=Recycling`, it can really improve the amount of memory used to display visual elements in your application so that you don't hit garbage collection nearly as often.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no time to test this answer, but it's very informative and looks right.